# Error on getSession usign Auth0 in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, auth0

I'm using App Router version of NextJS and I'm trying to implement authentication with Auth0 following the quickstart guide of this auth system.

I did all the steps and my app is redirecting to the Auth0 login and it makes the redirects after the user log in, but when I'm trying to get de session info I'm getting this error: `Cannot destructure property 'user' of '(intermediate value)' as it is null.`

My page is very simple and look like this

```
import { getSession } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

export default async function ProfileServer() {
  const { user } = await getSession();

  return (
      user && (
          <div>
            <img src={user.picture} alt={user.name} />
            <h2>{user.name}</h2>
            <p>{user.email}</p>
          </div>
      )
  );
}
```

I can't get a the session with the sample code of the quickstart, so I need some help :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```
    import { getSession } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

    export default async function ProfileServer() {
      const sessionInfo = await getSession();
    
      return (
        sessionInfo?.user && (
          <div>
            <img src={sessionInfo?.user.picture} alt={sessionInfo?.user.name} />
            <h2>{sessionInfo?.user.name}</h2>
            <p>{sessionInfo?.user.email}</p>
          </div>
        )
      );
    }
```